# PowerShell Activate Feature not working, but works when activating it in Site Features UI

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a PowerShell script that activates a custom feature.  This feature modifies some permissions on the current web it is activated on.  When activating it through the UI, all works fine.  I can see that the web breaks inheritance and permissions are modified for some SP Groups.  When I activate it through PowerShell, the feature activates, but inheritance remains and no groups are modified.
Would anyone have some insight as to why this might occur?  I have places some logging comments in the code, and they simply don't get hit.  I don't see any errors in the ULS logs either.  It's very odd and so I'm turning to the community.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you get an error in PowerShell? Any errors in logs? Do you call SPContext.Current or System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager in your code?

Comment: No errors are present when using PowerShell in the ULS logs.  No SPContext is being used.  To test, I put a ton of ULS tracing in the event receiver.  I then upgraded the solution.  When I activate it via Site Features, I see all the tracing entries in the ULS.  But when activating it via PowerShell, I don't see the tracing entries.  It's like it is using a previous version of the feature.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Wow that's really weird. Did you change scope of the feature? Did you try to deactivate feature and remove the solution and add it again (without using upgrade-spsolution)?

Comment: I got it work, but I'm not sure as to the reason why.  My PowerShell script did a series of things prior to activating the feature in question:  Create a new managed path, create a new site collection using this managed path, activate publishing features, etc.  The only thing I did differently this time was to remove all site collections using the same base managed path (i.e. pr/custom, pr/custom1, pr/custom2) prior to running the script.  does this make any sense that you might be able to explain?